# How to turn PDF page into image and insert it to a new PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, image-processing, itext

I am using Itext 7 to watermark existing documents. My document is:

```
   PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFile), new PdfWriter(destinationPath));
```

Then I am looping thro the pages:

```
var numberOfPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
   for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);

...watermark building...
page.AddAnnotation(watermark);

page?.Flush();

pdfDoc.Close();

}
```

While that I would like to save this page as an image into this document or to a new pdf document.
I know that there is the pdfRender available now for Java, but not for C#. Is there a way to save the text based pdf to image based with one leyer? Basically I need to flatten PDF to get all layers to one. So watermark could not be removed as a separate layer with a watermark removal software.

SOLUTION::UPDATE

I have the solution now. I found that iText cant do what I want(PDFRender is available in Java right now). So I used Apitron instead to generate images from pages. And then I am using iText again to add images to my new PDF document.
Here is an example how to add images with Itext 7: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/itext/itext_adding_image_to_pdf.htm (using Image = iText.Layout.Element.Image;)
Here is an Apitron example for making images from PDF pages: https://github.com/apitron/Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer.Samples/tree/master/ConvertPDFtoBitmap

NOTE: As comments below are saying, the quality is bad with .png. So maybe it is good to use TIFF format.

Comment: _"How to turn PDF page into image and insert it to a new PDF"_ - Sounds like a PDF sin.  Check out _["Types of PDF - Computerphile"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7oxZCgO1dY&t=17s)_, Professor Brailsford,   University of Nottingham. Particulary the [00:28](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7oxZCgO1dY&t=28s) mark.

Comment: Yes thanks. I know that it is not a good idea, and we need to aim best quality. But the point is, that I am dealing with already scanned PDFs. So there is already image and OCR text behind it.(in some cases).   I need somehow merge watermark with it.

Comment: If there already is an image, you should *extract* that image instead of *rendering* the page. The former is lossless, the latter is often lossy.